# i am getting error Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been block by cors policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-hooks, cors

I am working on MERN Project.
I am getting 503 service unavailable in the network tab [network 503](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmmPA.png) and in console cors origin blocked [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlYSj.png)

Also, whenever I am doing `npm start` in my backend file for few second server start and automatically no connection showing [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntqoK.png), I have checked on Heroku, there also I am getting error [heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eql8s.png).

Here is my server.js file [server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVQ7z.png) and frontend file where I am fetching data from Axios [product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68tU9.png).

Help me out to fix this error.

```
//in the server.js file I have tried,

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//for accepting all the http request
app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));

//also this

app.use(cors());

//Nothing works for me
```

Comment: There seems to be some configuration issue from Heroku. Please run `heroku ps:scale web=1`  command then check. Also never use origin * instead use actual URL you want to allow.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar With Express.js's CORS middleware, `origin: "*"` is harmless in most cases. It's `origin: true` that should never be used, esp. with `credentials: true`.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar i have try with actual path also, still getting the same error and where shoukd i run heroku command

Comment: @Neetugond You can run using cli and web interface. Look at [Running Commands on Heroku](https://tosbourn.com/running-commands-on-heroku/)